# Pandas: make list size in a column same as in another column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two columns: `serial_number` and `inv_number` containing lists. If there is one `inv_number` for multiple `serial_number`, I need to make the size of `inv_number`'s list the same as `serial_number`'s.

```
    serial_number                                       inv_number
28  [С029768, С029775]                                  [101040031171, 101040031172]
29  [090020960190402011, 090020960190402009]            [210134002523, 210134002524]
31  [1094]                                              [410124000215]
32  [01]                                                [101040022094]
33  [F161B5, F17D86, F17D8D, F1825C, F1825A, F1825D]    [101040026976]
```

Here at the index 33 we have 6 serial numbers but one inventory number, so it should be changed to

```
[101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976]
```

I've tried to do it by "multiplying" values to make a list (like `[value] * N`):

```
si.loc[si['inv_number'].apply(len)==1, 'inv_number'].apply
    (lambda x: [str(x[0])] * si['serial_number'].apply(len).values)
```

but it gives me an error:

> UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U12'), dtype('int64')) -> None

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: are the only two possibilities that the len of inv_number either matches that of serial_number else it is 1? how do you handle if `len(inv_number) == 2` and `len(serial_number) == 3` in a row

Comment: @AsishM. I've checked the rest of rows, it is fine, either N -> N, or N -> 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```py
mask = (df["serial_number"].str.len() > 1) & (df["inv_number"].str.len() == 1)
df.loc[mask, "inv_number"] = df["serial_number"].str.len() * df.loc[mask, "inv_number"]

print(df)
```

Prints:

```
                                       serial_number                                                                            inv_number
28                                [С029768, С029775]                                                          [101040031171, 101040031172]
29          [090020960190402011, 090020960190402009]                                                          [210134002523, 210134002524]
31                                            [1094]                                                                        [410124000215]
32                                              [01]                                                                        [101040022094]
33  [F161B5, F17D86, F17D8D, F1825C, F1825A, F1825D]  [101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976, 101040026976]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but why does it work with `str` while we have lists?

Comment: @Michael It's badly named. According to the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html#pandas.Series.str) it's vectorized string function and **index**. Works on strings, lists, tuples etc...

Answer (score 3):

With [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html), [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len) & [`mul`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mul.html) :

```
df["inv_number"] *= (-df.map(len).diff(axis=1).iloc[:, -1]).add(1)
```

|  | serial_number | inv_number |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | ['С029768', 'С029775'] | ['101040031171', '101040031172'] |
| 1 | ['090020960190402011', '090020960190402009'] | ['210134002523', '210134002524'] |
| 2 | ['1094'] | ['410124000215'] |
| 3 | ['01'] | ['101040022094'] |
| 4 | ['F161B5', 'F17D86', 'F17D8D', 'F1825C', 'F1825A', 'F1825D'] | ['101040026976', '101040026976', '101040026976', '101040026976', '101040026976', '101040026976'] |